# How can I save two plots on a single file in python?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot, save

I've got two different plots being generated. I need to save them both onto one '.png' file though. I would like to avoid using subplots, as when I do it seems to change the size and shape of my plots which I need to stay as they are. This is how my code looks currently:

```
fig = plt.figure(1)
    plt.clf()
    plot1(*args)
    plt.savefig('plot1.png')
    plot2(*args)
    plt.savefig('plot2.png')
```

Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it work for you to change the size of the figure and use `subplot()`?

default size is (8",6")

you could make it (16",6") and put them side-by-side?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax0.plot(*args0)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax1.plot(*args1)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('plots.png')
```

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to save multiple figures into a single file without using subplots if that is what you're looking for. This can be done using the `PdfPages` backend of `matplotlib`. Here a single file is created in which multiple times `savefig` can be called to save an image.

```
import numpy
import matplitlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

x = numpy.linspace(0, 100, 101)
y = numpy.cos(x)
z = numpy.sin(x)

cos_plot = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x, y)

sin_plot = plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(x, z)

pp = PdfPages("Cosine and sine plots.pdf")
pp.savefig(cos_plot, dpi = 300, transparent = True)
pp.savefig(sin_plot, dpi = 300, transparent = True)
pp.close()
```

Note that the options `dpi` and `transparent` are optional.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Typo in line 2: It should matplotlib instead of `matplitlib`. Otherwise it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

No, look into `plt.subplot()`. You can plot two plots in one figure and save that into one file.

Comment: It's just that when I do, it forces them to be of the same height, into a grid sort of configuration. Is there any way around that?